# I am not getting the mongoose queried user as the returned value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, react-apollo, apollo-server

This is my apollo resolver and I want to return the user but it does not return anything and if I return the query itself then I cannot do the password checking

my code:

```
login: (parent, { email, password }, context, info) => {
          User.findOne({ email }, function(err, user) {
            if (user.length) {
              bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, function(err, res) {
                if (res) {
                  console.log(user[0]); // this has the user
                  return user[0]; // but this does not return anything
                } else {
                  throw new ApolloError("failed");
                }
              });
            } else {
              throw new ApolloError("failed");
            }
          });
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to return something from a callback to an asynchronous operation (actually two layers deep into asynchronous operations). Nothing is paying attention to the return value.

Comment: I tried async await but it did not work either .. what do you suggest? cos I don't think I have any option with the validation logic

Comment: If those APIs can be used such that they return Promises you could use `async` and `await`, otherwise the login function will need its own callback to be invoked.

Comment: i even tried to declare a variable outside the query and populate it with the final result and it dit not work .. any reason for this to not work?

Comment: Right, no approach like that can possibly work. It's **asynchronous**. The call to `User.findOne()` returns immediately, and its callback won't be invoked until the database operation completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this solution and it is working perfectly

```
login: async (parent, { email, password }, context, info) => {
      const user = await attemptSignIn(email, password);

      return user;
    }

const attemptSignIn = async (email, password) => {
  const message = "Incorrect email or password. Please try again.";

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user || !(await matchesPassword(user, password))) {
    throw new AuthenticationError(message);
  }

  return user;
};

matchesPassword = (user, password) => {
  return compare(password, user.password);
};
```